# Why isn't dataChanged emitted after beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() in a subclass of QAbstractListModel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qml, pyside6

I was messing around with subclassing QAbstractListModel, and I don't think I understand how to properly add data to the model. Here's my script and the QML:

```js
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Sample Qt Quick application")
    width: 400
    height: 400
    color: "whitesmoke"

    Component.onCompleted: console.log("Component completed")

    Connections
    {
        target: main.custom_model
        function onDataChanged(topLeft, bottomRight, roles)
        {
            console.log("Custom model data changed")
        }
    }
    
}  // ApplicationWindow
```

```py
import sys

from random import randint
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QObject, QTimer, Property, QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class CustomModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._my_items = []
        
        self._role1 = Qt.UserRole + 1
        self._role2 = Qt.UserRole + 2
        
        self._roles = {
            self._role1: b"role1",
            self._role2: b"role2"
        }
        
    def append_item(self, arg1, arg2):
        row_count = self.rowCount()
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), row_count, row_count)

        self._my_items.append({
            self._roles[self._role1]: arg1,
            self._roles[self._role2]: arg2
        })

        self.endInsertRows()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        """
        Required for subclasses of QAbstractListModels
        """
        return len(self._my_items)

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        """
        Required for subclasses of QAbstractListModels
        """
        try:
            the_item = self._my_items[index.row()]
        except IndexError:
            return QVariant()

        if role in self._roles:
            key = self._roles[role]
            return the_item[key]

        return QVariant()

    def roleNames(self):
        return self._roles


class MainContextClass(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model = CustomModel()

    def add_an_item(self):
        thing1 = randint(0, 9)
        thing2 = randint(0, 9)
        print("Adding {0} and {1}".format(thing1, thing2))
        self._model.append_item(thing1, thing2)

    @Property(QObject, constant=True)
    def custom_model(self):
        return self._model


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    qml_app_engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    qml_context = qml_app_engine.rootContext()

    main_context = MainContextClass(parent=app)
    qml_context.setContextProperty("main", main_context)
    
    this_file_path = Path(__file__)
    main_qml_path = this_file_path.parent / 'example.qml'
    qml_app_engine.load(str(main_qml_path))

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.setInterval(1000)
    timer.setSingleShot(False)
    timer.timeout.connect(main_context.add_an_item)
    timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec())

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My expectation is that, every time the timer times out, a new row gets added to the listmodel, and therefore, the listmodel's `dataChanged` signal should get emitted. The `Connections` object's signal handler should then print a message. But it seems like it never executes:

```sh
$ python example.py
qml: Component completed
Adding 7 and 0
Adding 8 and 5
Adding 4 and 0
...
```

If I explicitly add `self.dataChanged.emit()` after `endInsertRows()`, then obviously the signal handler executes. But in all the documentation and example code I see, this isn't done. So, what's the proper approach?

Comment: That's when the `rowsInserted` signal is emitted, not `dataChanged` (which is when data in an existing item changes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dataChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) is emitted (explicitly) when the information of an item changes, when inserting rows then you should listen for the [`rowsAboutToBeInserted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsAboutToBeInserted) or [`rowsInserted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowsInserted) signals:

```
Connections {
    target: main.custom_model

    function onRowsAboutToBeInserted(parent, first, last) {
        console.log("before", parent, first, last);
    }

    function onRowsInserted(parent, first, last) {
        console.log("after", parent, first, last);
        /* print data
        let index = main.custom_model.index(first, 0, parent);
        let data1 = main.custom_model.data(index, Qt.UserRole + 1);
        let data2 = main.custom_model.data(index, Qt.UserRole + 2);
        console.log(data1, data2);*/
    }
}
```

On the other hand, in PySide there is no `QVariant`, instead you must return python objects, in the case of null QVariant you must return `None` (or nothing that is the same):

```py
def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    """
    Required for subclasses of QAbstractListModels
    """
    try:
        the_item = self._my_items[index.row()]
    except IndexError:
        return

    if role in self._roles:
        key = self._roles[role]
        return the_item[key]
```